# How to stop Eclipse rebuild workspace?

Tags: eclipse, workspace, rebuild

I have in  workspace near 70 projects. 
Sometimes Eclipse starts rebuild workspace, but I haven't made any modifications.
Rebuild takes near 2 hours. How to stop it and do Eclipse rebuild only projects in which modifications were made?
Thanks.

Comment: "Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Build Automatically" should turn off automatic building for the workspace

Comment: In general, Eclipse rebuilds only changed projects, and other projects that are dependent on the changes. Maybe one of your projects generates files for other project?

Comment: I have the same problem, with two different projects. One small, six projects using Eclipse Indigo. One big, 20+ projects using Eclipse Kepler/Luna. In both I experience rebuilds when I have not changed anything. But I want to build automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Menu, `Project -> Build Automatically` (Uncheck it)

Comment: already commented that, just realized I don't think that's what he means

Comment: I think you will find it is the other way around looking at the timestamps.