# What does it mean when Eclipse is building workspace?

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I renamed one of my projects, which contains quite a bit of files, and Eclipse would start rebuilding the workspace. This prevents me from doing anything since I can't save.

Will there be any drawbacks if you skip that process?

Comment: It's running all of the configured builders. Whether that's a problem or not depends on what those builders are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means Eclipse is rebuilding every relevant project in your namespace. See [Disable building workspace process in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505229/disable-building-workspace-process-in-eclipse) and [How to stop Eclipse rebuild workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878541/how-to-stop-eclipse-rebuild-workspace)

Comment: Thanks, but why does it need to build/rebuild the project? Every other IDE I've used seems to function properly without doing any of that (sorry I'm new to  using eclipse/pdt)

Comment: To show you your errors as soon as you save a file, I guess. Eclipse also functions properly without this. The question is why it's enabled by default. (I think it works like a charm in Java, but I'm not sure: I've never used it!)

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! Yeah I just tried editing a CSS file without building. Error checking seemed to be live, but content assist/code completion only works 10% of the time. Guess that's the drawback.

Comment: If you see a process such as "rebuilding index" do not cancel it, that should be the code assist. But it's still problematic. Apparently there's a "right click on project -> Index -> Rebuild" option in some development tools. Cross your fingers.

Comment: Yes, the indexing is extremely problematic for bigger projects. It usually takes at least an hour for me despite running on pretty fast hardware.

Comment: Ouch. You may want to report that to the developer tools' developers. (Or hopefully the build thing fixes it.)

Comment: Yeah, I reported to the bug tracker a day or two ago. Usually takes at least a few months before they finish the update packge though. Switched back to netbeans for now. It's a shame though, I actually found Eclipse/Aptana faster than netbeans while editing large scale projects, it's just that netbeans builds/scans the project within seconds.